# When exporting products, what string should I type in the filter option to skip any product with a missing SKU?

Tags: importexport

I'm attempting to export one Magento store to another. Though my store has thousands of products – about 10% have missing SKU's. I'm not sure how they were created without SKU's – I'm guessing they were half created when the admin timed out.

The point is, I'm assuming I can use the export filter option to narrow my export and skip any products that are missing this 'requirement' for import.

I'm fairly new to Magento and have no idea what to type in the filter to accomplish this.

This is my first time using Stackexchange so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not a coding answer, or an answer at all, for that mater, but I feel like rambling....and the comments area was to short ;)

You can easily create products without skus using the `Duplicate` button in the product admin. 
Click the button, then load the product grid in another window. You will find the product has already been inserted, without a sku. It is good habit to delete this entry, if you do not complete the save action on the duplicate.

It is also possible to initiate this process via code. You can, for example quickly create a new product this way. Simply duplicate the current product, manipulate the data pragmatically, and save. If something goes wrong, and is not correctly trapped, you may end up with the orphan records.

Just a thought, as an alternative solution: Simply delete them from the source db (meaning a copy you are working from) and then you don't have to bug around with getting the filters right. They are pointless data anyways, so why keep them?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, it's true they are pointless! I plan on removing them definitely at some point – though for the sake of time I was hoping this was an option etc. Do you know if it is by chance possible?

Essentially I have someone adding new products daily to the main Magento store, and then we'll be exporting at the end of the week to update the second store indefinitely.

In case this issue happens often enough I'm hoping this is the quickest way to avoid issues for this other person who isn't as capable etc.

Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know off the top of my head, and I don't have the time right now to investigate it.